# How to make a Timer.periodic function fire right away after calling it Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, timer

I'm trying to use a Timer.periodic function in flutter and it seems that when I call it, it waits for the specified duration that I put in for the time between callback triggers before actually going into the timer and firing off the code within. So if I put 2 mins for durationBetweenPayoutIterations, it waits 2 mins, then goes into the block and fires the callback every 2 mins.

How do you make it so that the timer starts right away and the code in the timer block starts executing right when you activate it?

```
Timer.periodic(durationBetweenPayoutIterations, (timer) async {
  // Code to be executed
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you mean that you want a periodic `Timer` where the initial callback is triggered immediately, you can write a helper function:

```dart
Timer makePeriodicTimer(
  Duration duration,
  void Function(Timer timer) callback, {
  bool fireNow = false,
}) {
  var timer = Timer.periodic(duration, callback);
  if (fireNow) {
    callback(timer);
  }
  return timer;
}
```

and then instead of using `Timer.periodic` directly, you could do:

```dart
var timer = makePeriodicTimer(duration, callback, fireNow: true);
```

Answer (score 1):

The current API does not provide to change it's behavior. But you can extract that inline function and call it yourself after starting the timer.

```
final timer = Timer.periodic(durationBetweenPayoutIterations, myCallback);
myCallback(timer);

myCallback(Timer timer) async {
  // Code to be executed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trick-method like this:

```
void _startTimerPeriodic(int millisec) {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: millisec), (Timer timer) async {
      // Your code here;

      if (millisec == 0) {
        timer.cancel();
        _startTimerPeriodic(1000 * 60 * 2);
      }
    });
  }
```

then call it the first time as:

```
_startTimerPeriodic(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this.

```
import 'dart:async';
 Timer? timer;

  @override
  initState() {
    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), ((timer) {
      getData();
    }));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    timer!.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> getData() async {}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a static method on the `Timer` class called `run` that will queue the callback to fire as-soon-as-possible.  So I recommend you do something like this:

```dart
timerCallback(Timer timer) {
  // Your code
}

// Start the periodic timer (and save it so you can cancel it later)
final timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), timerCallback);

// Now also try and run the callback immediately
Timer.run(timerCallback);
```

That way your first callback will use the same timer queue that all subsequent ones do, and you won't run into issues that may arise from calling your timer callback on the UI thread, like if you update your state in the callback and you are in the `build()` method, for example.